# Multiple belongs_to to same model only updating for last id in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, erb, nested-forms, belongs-to

So I have a User model and a Contract model with a many to many relationship. Contract belongs to multiple users but with different ids so i can do this

```
Contract.find(params[:id]).creator.email
Contract.find(params[:id]).leader.email
Contract.find(params[:id]).buyer.email
Contract.find(params[:id]).seller.email

User.find(params[:id]).contracts
```

In my form I have this, so I can set each id to an already created user

```html
<%= simple_form_for(@contract) do |f| %>
    <% if @contract.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h3><%= pluralize(@contract.errors.count, 'error') %> prohibited this contract from being saved:</h3>

          <ul>
            <% @contract.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :creator_id %><br>
      <%= f.select(:creator_id, User.all.map { |c| [c.email, c.id] }) %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :leader_id %><br>
      <%= f.select(:leader_id, User.all.map { |c| [c.email, c.id] }) %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :buyer_id %><br>
      <%= f.select(:buyer_id, User.all.map { |c| [c.email, c.id] }) %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :seller_id %><br>
      <%= f.select(:seller_id, User.all.map { |c| [c.email, c.id] }) %>
    </div>
    
<% end %>
```

My contract is created with each user id correctly set but when I check the user's contracts, I can only find the same contract if user was the seller (so the last div in the form)

Edit:
Here's my two models.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :contract, :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
  has_many :contract, :foreign_key => 'leader_id'
  has_many :contract, :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
  has_many :contract, :foreign_key => 'seller_id'

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :role, presence: true
end

class Contract < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
    belongs_to :leader, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'leader_id'
    belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
    belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
end
```

Contract controller:

```
class ContractsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_contract, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @contracts = Contract.all
  end

  def show
    @contract = Contract.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @contract = Contract.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @contract = Contract.new(contract_params)
    if @contract.save
      redirect_to contracts_path, notice: 'Le contract a été créé avec succès'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @contract.update(contract_params)
      redirect_to contract_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @contract.destroy
    redirect_to contracts_path
  end

  private
    def set_contract
      @contract = Contract.find(params[:id])
    end

    def contract_params
      params.require(:contract).permit(:creator_id,
                                       :leader_id,
                                       :buyer_id,
                                       :seller_id)
    end
end
```

I need to have each of the selectors updating the chosen user but only the last one is working and I can't figure out how to make it work.

I feel like this approach can work but I'm new in rails and maybe I'm using the wrong method.
I tried a simple has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, creating users like explained here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html under 'Building Complex Forms' but I lost the distinction between each specific user in the form when I set them with a field-for

Hope I'm clear enough, thanks !

Comment: Could you drop your Model definitions as well?

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: Let me know if my suggestion worked, I am quite curious if not using plural with has_many does this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so you have a couple of problems with your model definition.

1. Your relationship needs to be plural if you are using `has_many`, so it'll be `has_many :contracts`. This is most probably what is causing your problem.
2. It's not the best idea to have multiple foreign keys to the same table. Instead have one `has_many :contracts, foreign_key: 'contractor_id'`. But then use a separate variable to define the role of the `User`. And in `Contract` you'll have `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'contractor_id'`. You can then specify custom accessor_methods if you want to call `creator`, `leader`, etc

Comment: Contracts were plural in my code, made a typo when rewriting it here with easier terms. I understand what you're proposing with the variable for role and the accessor_methods but I need to keep a many to many relationship between contracts and users though. My contract will always have 4 users associated

Comment: Not sure how my view should work if I don't have the ids anymore too. Could you give me more detailled snippets on how I should implement all this ?

Comment: Ok, for me to write a full solution for your case, I'll need you to add your controller and the whole view to get a better picture. Thinking about this again, I do think you'll need has_and_belongs_to_many, so I think you not finding a way to distinguish users was the step missing for you to make it work.

Comment: I added controller and full form to the question